# Invalid JSON response, on trying to send data from the form to action file

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I am trying to make a Student Attendance system.

1. I have successfully implemented a front view table, which will display all the dates for which attendance records have been taken.
2. I have also successfully implemented "Add Attendance" function in which new attendance record is taken for the students of the class

Now, I am trying to create a function for "Edit Attendance Record" for each of the row. That is, for every specific date, the teacher would be able to edit the attendance record of students...
I have managed to obtain data (which is presently stored) from database of the students for the "selected" date and it displays the data fine as well...

Just so as to give an idea, here's the Modal I am using for Edit Attendance.

```
<div id = "edit_attendance_model" class = "modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog mw-100 w-75">
        <form action="post" id = "edit_attendance_form">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <h4 class = "modal-title">Edit Attendance Record</h4>
                    <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body">
                    <div class ="form-group">
                        <div class = "row">
                            <label class = "col-md-4 text-right">Attendance Date</label>
                            <div class = "col-md-8">
                                <input readonly = "true" type="date" name = "edit_attendance_date" id = "edit_attendance_date" class = "form-control" />
                                <span id = "error_edit_attendance_date" class = "text-danger"></span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group" id = "edit_student_details">
                        <div class = "table-responsive">
                            <table id = "edit-table" class = "table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Roll Number</th>
                                        <th>Student Name</th>
                                        <th>Attendance Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" name = "edit_attendance_submit" id = "edit_attendance_submit" class = "btn btn-success" value = "Update Attendance" />
                    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the Jquery code, which takes the data (currently stored) from the database and shows it on the modal.

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_attendance_record', function(e){
            var attendance_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
            $.ajax({
                url: "attendance_action.php", 
                method: "POST", 
                data: {attendance_id:attendance_id, action: "edit-form"},
                dataType: 'json', 
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#edit_attendance_date").val(attendance_id); // Here I assign value to attendance_date
                    $.each(data, function(index, value){
                        $("edit-table tbody").append('<input type="hidden" name = "student_id[]" value = "'+ value[0] +'">');
                        $("#edit-table tbody").append('<tr><td>' + value[3] + '</td><td>' + value[2] + '</td><td>' + value[1] + '</td></tr>');
                    });
                    $("#edit_attendance_model").modal('show'); 
                }
            });
        });
```

Here's the PHP code,

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "edit-form")
{
    $attendance_id = $_POST["attendance_id"];
    $data = $db->get_attendance_date_record($attendance_id, $id); 
    echo json_encode($data); 

}
```

And this is my Database code, to get data from database using SQL

```
public function get_attendance_date_record($att_date, $teacher_id)
    {
      

      $data = array();
      $sql = "select a.student_id, (select name from tbl_student s where s.id = a.student_id) as name, (select username from tbl_student z where z.id = a.student_id) as username, status from junc_attendance a where att_date = :att_date and classroom_id = (select id from tbl_classroom where teacher_id = :teacher_id)";

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql); 
      $stmt->execute(['att_date'=>$att_date, 'teacher_id'=>$teacher_id]);
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $number = 1; 
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
        $sub_array = array(); 
        $sub_array[] = $row["student_id"];
        if ($row["status"] == "Present")
        {
          $sub_array[] = '<input type="radio" name = "edit_attendance_status'.$row["student_id"].'" checked value = "Present" /><label for="Present">Present</label><input type="radio" name = "edit_attendance_status'.$row["student_id"].'" value = "Absent" /><label for="Absent">Absent</label><input type="radio" name = "edit_attendance_status'.$row["student_id"].'" value = "Leave" /><label for="Leave">Leave</label>';
        }
        if ($row["status"] == "Absent")
          $sub_array[] = '<input type="radio" name = "edit_attendance_status<'.$row["student_id"].'" value = "Present" /><label for="Present">Present</label><input type="radio" name = "edit_attendance_status'.$row["student_id"].'" checked value = "Absent" /><label for="Absent">Absent</label><input type="radio" name = "edit_attendance_status'.$row["student_id"].'" value = "Leave" /><label for="Leave">Leave</label>';
        if ($row["status"] == "Leave")
          $sub_array[] = '<input type="radio" name = "edit_attendance_status'.$row["student_id"].'" value = "Present" /><label for="Present">Present</label><input type="radio" name = "edit_attendance_status'.$row["student_id"].'" value = "Absent" /><label for="Absent">Absent</label><input type="radio" name = "edit_attendance_status'.$row["student_id"].'" checked value = "Leave" /><label for="Leave">Leave</label>';
        $sub_array[] = $row["name"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["username"];
        $data[] = $sub_array; 
      }
      return $data; 
    }
```

However, the problem occurs when I try to implement the "Update Attendnace" button, which is supposed to submit the record and update it in the database.
**I have implemented Update Attendance exactly same as Add Attendance. Add Attendnace is working, but Update Attendance is not, and I can't figure out why.**

Following is the Jquery code for the submit button on Edit Attendance Modal.
Please note that I have already tested the values for "Date" and also the "form data" and they seem to be pretty correct.

```
$("#edit_attendance_form").on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    //alert($("#edit_attendance_date").val()); -> I checked it up, and it gave perfect result. 
    //alert($(this).serialize()); -> This also gives correct results here. 
    $.ajax({
        url:"attendance_action.php", 
        method: "POST", 
        data: $(this).serialize()+"&action=edit_attendance", 
        dataType: 'json', 
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#edit_attendance_submit").val("Validating...."); 
            $("#edit_attendance_submit").attr('disabled', true); 
            $att = ("edit_attendance_date").val(); 
            alert(att); 
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            $("#add_attendance_submit").val("Update Attendance"); 
            $("#add_attendance_submit").attr('disabled', false);
            if (data.success)
            {
                $('#message_operation').html('<div class = "alert alert-success">'+data.success+'</div>');
                $('#edit_attendance_modal').modal('hide');
                table.ajax.reload();  
            } 
            if (data.error)
            {
                if (data.error_attendance_date != '')
                    $("#error_attendance_date").text(data.error_attendance_date);
                else 
                    $("#error_attendance_date").text('');
            }
            
        },
        error: function(e)
            {
                alert("Failed to update attendnace record."); 
                $("#add_attendance_submit").val("Update Attendance"); 
                $("#add_attendance_submit").attr('disabled', false);
            }
    });
});
```

This is the result I got when I printed out the result of $(this).serialize(). This is what I would be sending whenever the "Update Attendance" button is clicked on, it seems to be quite ok..

[image: $(this).serialize() result from Edit_Attendance_Modal]

**The problem occurs here.. Following is my code that captures the result from the form and then performs action on it. Whenever I try to add this code in my action file, my page fails to load and it says INVALID JSON RESPONSE**.
The code is as follows.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] = "edit_attendance")
{
    $attendance_date = '';  
    $error_attendance_date = ''; 
    $output = ''; 
    $error = 0;
    $attendance_date = $_POST['edit_attendance_date'];
    $student_id = $_POST['student_id']; 
    for ($count = 0; $count < count($student_id); $count++)
    {
        $attendance_status = $_POST["edit_attendance_status".$student_id[$count].""]; 
        $s_id = $student_id[$count]; 
        $db->iupdate_attendance_table($s_id, $attendance_status, $attendance_date, $id); // Where $id is teacher id

    }
    $output = array(
        'success'               => 'Data Updated Successfully'
    );
    
    
    echo json_encode($output); 
}
```

After having added this code to the file, my page wouldn't even load... Wouldn't even show the first table which shows all the records... It shows the error "Invalid JSON Response" and this is what the response looks like from the action file,

```
{"data":[["Lecture 1","2020-07-07","Tuesday","1","Edit<\/a>    Delete<\/a>"],["Lecture 2","2020-07-08","Wednesday","1","Edit<\/a>    Delete<\/a>"],["Lecture 3","2020-08-02","Sunday","1","Edit<\/a>    Delete<\/a>"],["Lecture 4","2020-08-04","Tuesday","1","Edit<\/a>    Delete<\/a>"],["Lecture 5","2020-08-05","Wednesday","3","Edit<\/a>    Delete<\/a>"],["Lecture 6","2020-08-06","Thursday","1","Edit<\/a>    Delete<\/a>"],["Lecture 7","2020-08-13","Thursday","3","Edit<\/a>    Delete<\/a>"],["Lecture 8","2020-08-15","Saturday","2","Edit<\/a>    Delete<\/a>"]]}
```

Notice: Undefined index: edit_attendance_date in E:\Softwares\XAMP\htdocs\school\teacher\attendance_action.php on line 86

```
Notice: Undefined index: student_id in E:\Softwares\XAMP\htdocs\school\teacher\attendance_action.php on line 87

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in E:\Softwares\XAMP\htdocs\school\teacher\attendance_action.php on line 88
{"success":"Data Updated Successfully"}
```

The first response is a simple JSON returned data, which is supposed to print on the loading of the page... The JSON data is fine (also tested on jsonlint.com) and it also works if I remove the above code from the Action file...

The next two lines, I don't get why... Attendance date that is being sent is fine (as I tested), also the student_id should also be fine... The last error is understandable because student_id is not being read properly.
Can anyone help here?

Comment: First, please change this: if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] = "edit_attendance" ... to "==". Then see what changes. Also, which is: attendance_action.php on *line 86*?

Comment: oh... my... god... ^_^ 
man, thank you :( I don't know why I missed that, especially after having checked it multiple times... Thank you. That fixed the issue :| :| :|